# How Application is interacting with hardware in linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am new in Linux and i want to know the internals of drivers and how it is interacting with hardware, so my question is that `How the application is interacting with hardware` means when the `core part` will come in picture and what it will do?

When the `controller` of that driver will come and how it will handle the request generated by the application.

And what is `Firmware` and when it comes into picture in Linux?

```
For eg: if i am using usb device like 
$ cat /dev/usb0.1 
then which is the core of usb(usb_storage.c) and 
which is the controller(usb_hub.c)
and how they are related to each other.
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Basically linux kernel driver provide interface such as device file node then application can use standard read()/write()/ioctl() to pass parameter to operate hardware. Provide interface in /proc or /sys can be facilities to do that too. Detail implementation how to handle request depends on respective hardware spec.